# How to add a new System DSN which connected to MS DB using JAVA instead of odbc32.exe?

Tags: java, odbc

I am trying to Add new System  DSN But I want use java Instead using Windows `odbcad32.exe`.

My issues is :

- I am creating java application that connected with database, but instead of the main database
  I create another database in some file,this Database containing some special information that is hidden from the user.
  NOTE: I don't use `odbcad32.exe`  use Just java .
  if it's not possible , is there any other suggestion ?

Thanks for reading .

Answer (score 1):

If you can determine which Win32 API functions are called by `odbcad32.exe`,
then you can call those functions.

Here are two options for doing this:

1. [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) seems [the industry standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) of what you want, "provides Java programs easy access to native shared libraries (DLLs on Windows) without writing anything but Java code—no JNI or native code is required"
2. There is also [Java Foreign Function Interface](http://github.com/wmeissner/jffi) -
   [example usage](http://github.com/wmeissner/jffi/blob/0.6/test/com/kenai/jffi/StructTest.java)

Comment: Thanks for helping  I could't find the my point but +1 for your answer it was a good information .